# Windows 7 PC, Google blocked. All other sites OK

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, hosts-file

All google sites seem blocked with "This page can't be displayed" Error. I can ping all the google servers but even trying the IP doesn't work. Same message.

I have checked hosts files. I have done combofix, Malware Bytes, Ccleaner. I have manually searched the registry for a sneaky pest. Full AV scan completed. 
Same using Chrome and Firefox, so it's not IE.

Comment: Can you access google on another computer or device? Trying to Rule out the Router also. Because I know you can ping a website even if its blocked because it blocks the hostname.

Comment: Yes mate. I have other devices and they all are fine

Comment: Are you on IPV6 or IPV4? I would Try and changing your DNS to see if this fixes it. Click [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#important_before_you_start) for a Reference. I would also check to see if you have a proxy that may have blocked google. Click [here](http://www.gvsu.edu/it/simplesolutions/checking-the-network-proxy-settings-in-windows-7-32.htm) for the Reference on that. Also when did this happen? Just all of a sudden or were you doing something?

Comment: What does google sites mean? Can you confirm that you are visiting this site on the same computer ? Anything odd with your hosts file, anything odd with your firewall and any rules in the router?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. No matter what setting I use it remains the same. No proxy deviations found and using DHCP or manually entering details doesn't matter. Is there anywhere except the \drivers\etc folder from where windows references Hosts files? It appears to immediately bounce the error without looking out which makes me think it's a hosts file problem. Head scratcher

Comment: google.com or co.uk or .ie even same error as is Gmail by the way

Comment: OK guys, for anyone interested, and this is some Derren Brown s&^t. I went into Internet Options, Privacy, Sites and added www.google.co.uk to the allow list. And the f*&^%$ worked!!!!! I hasten to add there was NOTHING in the list at all, nothing either blocked or allowed. I'm thinking a corrupt cookie or something but I dunno guys. Thank you all for the suggestions, it's nice to have the luxury of time to try everything, even though one of my guys wanted to re-image! Solved! Sort of, now I wonder how it happened? LOL

Answer (score 1):

OK guys, for anyone interested, and this is some Derren Brown s&^t. I went into Internet Options, Privacy, Sites and added www.google.co.uk to the allow list. And the f*&^%$ worked!!!!! I hasten to add there was NOTHING in the list at all, nothing either blocked or allowed. I'm thinking a corrupt cookie or something but I dunno guys. Thank you all for the suggestions, it's nice to have the luxury of time to try everything, even though one of my guys wanted to re-image! Solved! Sort of, now I wonder how it happened? LOL

Comment: Very interesting

Comment: "Internet Options, Privacy, Sites" - What program?  Vulgarity mask or otherwise isn't appreciated.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry if my "vulgarity" offended you but I don't really care for your condescending tone either. In my experience, Internet Options *usually* implies one of the Microsoft Internet Explorer browsers. If I'm still not being clear. It was Microsoft Internet Explorer 11.